# DISTRIBUTE BY & CLUSTER BY in Spark-SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I just got introduced to Spark-SQL. Although I have previous experience in RDBMS sql (Oracle, Teradata, Sql Server etc), I am looking for expanding my knowledge in Spark-SQL why learning advanced functions/concepts in Spark-SQL.

So I came across the clauses DISTRIBUTE BY & CLUSTER BY during the process. However, I haven't been able to figure out if these clauses work in Spark SQL , and if they do, how they work.

Hence, can anyone point me in the right direction ? It will be great if someone explained these 2 clauses with some examples (provided they could be used in Spark-Sql) and also point me to resources for learning advanced functions of Spark-Sql.

Thanks.

Comment: This question should be closed because it is asking for off-site resources.  I accidentally chose the wrong close reason, so I had to retract my close vote.